# Sails - Access Controller function(req,res) from Service

Tags: model-view-controller, sails.js

I have a Controller method: `DbController.create` to create database entries. This is the following format:

```
create: function (req, res) {
    var params = req.body;
    Db.create({
...
```

There is a route for this Controller method:

```
 'POST /createData': 'DbController.create'
```

I can use CURL to this URL with no problems (`curl -X POST --data 'userId="testuser1"' http://localhost:1337/createData`), and from my UI code I can call this using sails-io.js and `io.socket.post(....)`.

The problem is that I want to use this from my Service now (DbService). I'm not sure how I can go about this, because simply using `DbController.create` requires a `req` and `res` parameter to be passed, but all I have is the data/params/body.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to move the `create` logic in some `service` method so that it can be used from anywhere in project. Once this is done, then invoke that method with necessary parameters from `DbController.create` as well as from some other service.

Sample:

```
// DBService:

createData: (params, callback) => {
    Db.create(params)...
}

// DBController:

create: (req, res) => {
    const params = req.body;
    DBService.createData(params, (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.serverError(err);
        }
        return res.json(results);
    });
}

// SomeOtherService:

someMethod: (params, callback) => {
    DBService.createData(params, callback);
}
```

Another way (which will unnecessary make http request) is to make a HTTP call from service to the API endpoint of `DbController.create` from the service.

Comment: Cheers, this is the only way to go about it. I was trying to keep the controller functions in the controller but it makes sense to create a service for the controller too.